# Ensure Android's Overflow button does not come up on my Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I implemented the overflow button myself using the following base XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
        android:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_logout"
                android:title="Log out"
                android:showAsAction="never" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_offer_advice"
                android:title="Advice"
                android:showAsAction="never" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create"
        android:title="Create"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_new"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>



</menu>
```

I did this because I want the Overflow button to be on every Android device regardless of a physical menu button. I opted for this over the hacky solution offered many times across Stackoverflow. That being said, I'm a bit fuzzy with ActionBars and I want to be positive that Android's default overflow won't show up for users that don't have a physical menu button. It would be very awkward to have my implementation of the overflow button with Android's default one right next to it.

Am I worrying over nothing? Is this a legitimate concern? If it is a legitimate concern, what could I do to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say that this is not a concern. There are many apps native to the Android operating system (ex. the gallery app) that show the overflow menu despite the device having a physical menu button.

Another situation you may not have considered is the possibility that the user's menu button is not functional on the device, causing your action bar tidying to become a problem.

There is undoubtably a way to achieve this, but what you're trying to achieve may cause more problems than solve.